# What fallacies are these? (because someone said so)

Tags: phrase-requests

What fallacies are these arguments? If they are.

Statement: The earth is flat.

Argument (1) You're incorrect! The earth is round because NASA scientists/geography experts/etc. said so. (Experts from the related fields)

Argument (2) You're incorrect! The earth is round because those coders at StackOverFlow said so. (Irrelevant people)

Argument (3) You're incorrect! The earth is round because many people said so.

Comment: You might get more appropriate answers on philosophy.SE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to the English language or its usage. As @Mitch says, you might be able to ask over on [Philosophy.se], but make sure to read their rules first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three are logical fallacies.

1. Arguing based on the views of relevant experts is called an *appeal to authority*:

> An **argument from authority**, also called an **appeal to authority**, or the **argumentum ad verecundiam**, is a form of defeasible argument in which a claimed authority's support is used as evidence for an argument's conclusion. It is well known as a fallacy, though it is used in a cogent form when all sides of a discussion agree on the reliability of the authority in the given context.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority)

2. Arguing based on the views of irrelevant experts is called an *argument from false authority*:

> When a person making a claim is presented as an expert who should be trusted when his or her expertise is not in the area being discussed.
>   [- Logically Fallacious](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/231/Argument-from-False-Authority)

3. Arguing based on the views of the crowd: *appeal to popularity* of *argumentum ad populum*, etc:

> In argumentation theory, an **argumentum ad populum** (Latin for "**argument to the people**") is a fallacious argument that concludes that a proposition must be true because many or most people believe it, often concisely encapsulated as: "If many believe so, it is so."
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum)

Comment: It would be interesting to know what logical arguments are _not_ fallacious as the above is a very broad exclusion.

Comment: @NigelJ Any arguments that are not based on the data should be considered fallacious in the technical sense. Appeals to authority come closest to being valid, but they assume (without proof) that the authority maintains logical consistency with the underlying data. I should add that logical validity, argument persuasiveness, and truth are not necessarily the same thing. So an appeal to authority may be unsound logically but still persuasive and perhaps reliable, while a logically sound argument (say, based on a wonky interpretation of the facts) might not be reliable as a determiner of truth.

Comment: My understanding is that there is nothing fallacious about citing authority and using it as a grounds for an ~opinion~.  ~ "Based on published observations made by NASA and their explanations, I have come to the opinion that the world is round. I have seen no viable alternative data that could lead me to any meaningful level of uncertainty." That is a take it or leave it fact..I've read and decided. "The earth is round" could turn into a weird semantic argument anyway."( Must a sphere be perfect to be round? is the atmosphere part of the 'earth' .. 'oceans aren't earth' ... lol asinineness)

Comment: @Tom22 Certainly, you can form *opinions* on bases other than logic - that's consistent with the comment I left above. However, it is a (logical) fallacy to assert that something is true *just* because someone else said it was (except, of course, the self-referential case where their opinion *is* the data, as opposed to simply being *about* the data).

Comment: @Tom22 Yes, there is, but your example relates more to data attribution than actual argument.The *estimates* version is a statement about bureau's estimate whereas the *according to* version is a statement about attribution, but this is splitting hairs. ...

Comment: @Tom22 ... I take *argument* to refer to conclusions drawn from data. For example, "Based on average dietary intake studies and estimates of the US population, the US needs an edible protein supply of *xyz* kg each day." *vs* "The US needs an edible protein supply of *xyz* kg each day because Dr So-and-so said so." The conclusion of the latter may still be true, but even if it is true, the truth isn't so just *because* someone said so. The logical dependency is fallacious.